# msoHyperlinkInlineShape doesn't work for inline images

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

Here is a macro, which allows to replace hyperlinks across images.

(How to use it: copy some images to document, then add hyperlinks to each of them, for example, www.google.com, and then, using this macro, you can replace these hyperlinks to something different, for example www.stackoverflow.com. Test file uploaded here: https://ufile.io/qbdcp).

At first, I tried to use

```
If .Type = msoHyperlinkInlineShape
```

but for some reason, it doesn't work for inline images, which were copied from file manager (Ctrl-C in file manager, Ctrl-V in Word).

Then, I replaced it to

```
If .Type = msoHyperlinkShape
```

and now it works.

But I still wondering why I was forced to change `msoHyperlinkInlineShape` to `msoHyperlinkShape`, whereas I use **inline** pictures. Why `msoHyperlinkInlineShape` doesn't work?

```
Sub ReplaceHyperlinks()
    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sRepl As String
    Dim iCnt As Integer

    sFind = InputBox("Find what", "Find Hyperlink")
    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    sRepl = InputBox("Replace with", "Replace Hyperlink")
    If Len(sRepl) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    iCnt = 0
    For Each HL In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        With HL

            If .Type = msoHyperlinkShape Then ' msoHyperlinkInlineShape will not work for some reason

                If InStr(LCase(.Address), LCase(sFind)) Then
                    .Address = Replace(.Address, sFind, sRepl, , , vbTextCompare)
                    .ScreenTip = Replace(.ScreenTip, sFind, sRepl, , , vbTextCompare)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    .Range.Fields.Update
                    iCnt = iCnt + 1
                End If
                If InStr(LCase(.TextToDisplay), LCase(sFind)) Then
                    .TextToDisplay = Replace(.TextToDisplay, sFind, sRepl, , , vbTextCompare)
                    .Range.Fields.Update
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    MsgBox ("Links replaced: " & iCnt)
End Sub
```

Comment: By asking which other thing is like a Shape you ask to learn two things instead of one. An InlineShape is like a character in a string. It is inserted anywhere where you might also insert a single character, breaking the text at that point, and text resumes thereafter. A Shape, on the other hand, is an object anchored to a paragraph. It is positioned relative to that paragraph, anywhere on the page, irrespective of any text. In practise, it is rather hard to arrange text all around a Shape, but to an InlineShape that comes naturally.

Comment: @Variatus Thank you very much. I think so too. But I can't understand why the code works so strangely. I mean, why `msoHyperlinkShape` works for inline pictures (if they were pasted from file manager), whereas `msoHyperlinkInlineShape` works only for images inserted via `IncludePicture` field.

Comment: @Variatus Also I rewrited the question, now it looks much shorter and simpler.

Comment: **To everybody.** Wow, it's stange, that there was no answers or even comments since I edited the question and opened a bounty. Probably my question is not clear enough. Please let me know.

Comment: @johnc.j. Does it work now ?

Comment: @Teasel It works, but I don't understand why I was forced to change `msoHyperlinkInlineShape` to `msoHyperlinkShape`, whereas I use **inline** pictures.

Comment: are you really sure that you are using ***inline*** pictures?

Comment: @jsotola Hm, I'm sure. Maybe I'm wrong, but from my point of view, yes, it is inline pictures. Test file is attached at the top of the question.